# Include full term name including "in" "and" etc when used for URL alias

Tags: path-aliases

Im using taxonomy terms to create my URL aliases. At the moment the word "in" is stripped out.

So if the term was "Fun in London"

The URL created would be "fun-london".

How can I include the full path? So I would have "fun-in-london".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose "strings to remove" on the settings page:

/admin/config/search/path/settings